# Apache 2.4 as a Reverse Proxy for RabbitMQ web socket

Tags: apache, websocket, rabbitmq, reverse-proxy

I have two machines:

1. Public web server - Apache 2.4, Ubuntu (eg. 194.204.159.1 domain.net)
2. Private server - RabbitMQ server + Web Socket, Ubuntu (eg. 192.168.0.10)

I need to configure Apache 2.4 on server 1. as Reverse Proxy for communication with Web Socket server 2. Server 1. is connected with server 2.

On server 1. I have a Javascript script that should get a messages from queue from server 2. via Web Socket (RabbitMQ Web MQTT Plugin).

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var wsbroker = location.hostname;
    var wsport = 15675;
    
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport, "/ws",
        "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
    
    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
        console.log("CONNECTION LOST - " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    };
    
    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
        console.log("RECEIVE ON " + message.destinationName + " PAYLOAD " + message.payloadString);
    };
    
    var options = {
        timeout: 5,
        useSSL: true,
        userName: 'websocket',
        password: 'websocket',
        onSuccess: function () {
            console.log("CONNECTION SUCCESS");
            client.subscribe('/vhost/mqtt-queue', {qos: 0});
        },
        onFailure: function (message) {
            console.log("CONNECTION FAILURE - " + message.errorMessage);
        }
    };
</script>
```